# How can I use MockMvc in Spring MVC 2.5 project?

Tags: java, spring

MockMvc is introduced in Spring Test 3.2. I have an old project depending on Spring MVC 2.5 which is hard to upgrade (too many things to get around). I'd like to use MockMvc to do integration tests.

Code like this:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import redis.embedded.RedisServer;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/afdspplicationContext*.xml",
        "/applicationContext*.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ScheduleControllerTest {
    private static RedisServer redisServer;
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws IOException {

        redisServer = new RedisServer(45678);
        redisServer.start();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        redisServer.stop();
    }
    @Test
    public void getRoomStatusByDateAndBuilding() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/recommend/checkin?userName=dd&roomName=f"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("\"code\":422")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("test")));
    }
}
```

However, test ended up with error:

> objc[77723]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
>   (0x10bc614c0) and
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib
>   (0x10bcd14e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load
>   CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate [class
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:101)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createBootstrapContext(BootstrapUtils.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.createCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate(BootstrapUtils.java:98)
>     ... 18 more
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

Maybe this error occurs because of mismatching Spring MVC 2.5 with Spring Test 4.3.9. Does any workaround exist, to let me use MockMvc while still keep using Spring MVC 2.5?

Comment: You cannot. Never mix jars of different versions of a framework as that will lead to issues. Upgrade the whole framework to a newer version (generally a drop-in replacement).

Answer (score 1):

Spring 2.5 was released 11 years ago (19 Nov 2007) and is not officially supporting Java 7 which you are attempting to use. As per [Spring Framework 2.5 Released](https://spring.io/blog/2007/11/19/spring-framework-2-5-released):

> - Full Java 6 and Java EE 5 support (JDBC 4.0, JTA 1.1, JavaMail 1.4, JAX-WS 2.0)

You are running a very unusual and error prone setup. Upgrade Spring or recreate and backport `MockMvc` framework yourself and downgrade to Java 6. Don't mix 2.5 and 3.2 dependencies, this will create a lot of classpath problems like you just observed.

I'd argue that upgrading Spring after 11 years is not the worst investment of developers time.